# How to import a excel file which contains more than 100,000 rows in Mathematica

Tags: excel, wolfram-mathematica

I have a Microsoft Excel file which contains 110,000 rows of data. When I import the file using the command `Import` in Mathematica, I found out that it can only import about 60,000 rows and hence lots of data in the original excel file was lost, and the original file was truncated to a 60,000 rows file.

Comment: You might want to ask this on mathematica.stackexchange.com.  You might also want to post the full detail of your Import command.

Comment: Which version of Excel was used for creating the file, what extension it has (.xls or .xlsx)? In Excel 2003 spreadsheets are limited to 65536 rows.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov So probably that's not the one :D

Comment: If the kind of data you manipulate allows, you might be better off going through another format such as CSV, TAB, ...

Comment: just tried this.. mathematica9 throws a 'java heapspace' error importing large excel (excel 2010 xlsx) files (simple files with all numbrs). Dito on the save as csv.  Same file imports from csv no problem.  Highly disturbing if import actually corrupted your original file.